# How to combine 2 c# Expression of different type in Devforce?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, devforce

I wrote some predicates and would like to them to construct an entity query.

Usually if I have an entity of type `EntityA` I will write this kind of expression `Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>>`.

What I want to accomplish is using `Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>>` in an query of type `EntityA`.

Let's say `EntityA` have a collection of `EntityB`. I have a predicate on `EntityA` like :

```
public static Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> HasId(int id)
{
    return p => p.Id == id;
}
```

Now while querying my EntityB I would like to be able to use this predicate in order to avoid to rewrite it in a `Expression<EntityB, bool>> (with p => p.EntityA.Id == id)`.

I would like to have something like :

```
Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> predicates = p => **initial condition on EntityB**
var myfunc = HasId(12).Compile();
predicates = predicates.And(p => myfunc(p.EntityA));
```

This syntax doesn't work.

How can I use a `Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>>` in a `Expression<Func<EntityB,bool>>` predicate?

*** EDIT ***

Forgot to mention I am using Devforce (from Ideablade) in my project.
The predicates.And is from them (I initially thought I was from the system).

The error Message is :

Unknown Expression type: Invoke(value(UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass1).myfunc , p.EntityA)

and the Stacktrace is :

```
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.<VisitExpressions>b__0(Expression e)
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   à System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressions(IEnumerable`1 expressions)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.TransformExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionCore(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.Linq.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expr)
   à IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQuery`1.ProcessExpression(Expression e)
   à IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQuery`1..ctor(Expression expression, IQueryable queryable)
   à IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.CreateQuery[TElement](Expression expression)
   à System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   à IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryExtensions.Where[TSource](IEntityQuery`1 source1, Expression`1 predicate)
```

Comment: You say that "This syntax doesn't work", but what error(s) do you get?

Comment: Likely he is using LinqKit - which includes extension methods for Expressions.

Comment: I noticed you did `predicates.And(...)`. What are you trying to do there? Note that there is a **static** method `Expression.And(Expression, Expression)` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301748.aspx)). However, its syntax requires **two** expression arguments (@Mike, or perhaps he is using LinqKit instead...)

Comment: Edited, I in fact use Devforce from Ideablade. the helper "And" is provided by them, I though it was something common in the c# library. What I want to acheive is combining multiple Expression<Func>> while some target the main entity of the query and others some navigation property

Comment: DevForce doesn't support the Invoke because it can't serialize the function call when serializing the expression tree to the server.  Although you probably won't be able to use your existing predicates, some of the other dynamic query features in DevForce may still help - take a look at PredicateBuilder and PredicateDescription [here](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/dynamic-where).

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `Expression<EntityB,bool>` predicate dynamically but it's re-usability is questionable.  Do note that invoke expressions are not supported if using Entity Framework.

-- update

This works and is reusable:

```
public static Expression<Func<T2, bool>> SubPredicate<T1, T2>( Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T2, T1>> selector )
{
    var parms = selector.Parameters;

    var a = Expression.Invoke( selector, parms );

    var invocation = Expression.Invoke( predicate, a );

    return ( Expression<Func<T2, bool>> )Expression.Lambda( invocation, parms );
}
```

Usage:

```
var filteredResults = list.Where( 
    SubPredicate<EntityA, EntityB>( 
        a => a.ID % 2 == 1, 
        b => b.EntityA )
        .Compile() );
```

-- demo:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var list = new List<EntityB>()
    {
        new EntityB()
        {
            ID = 11,
            EntityA = new EntityA() { ID = 1 }
        },
        new EntityB()
        {
            ID = 22,
            EntityA = new EntityA() { ID = 2 }
        },
        new EntityB()
        {
            ID = 33,
            EntityA = new EntityA() { ID = 3 }
        },
    };

    var filteredResults = list.Where( 
        SubPredicate<EntityA, EntityB>( 
            a => a.ID % 2 == 1, 
            b => b.EntityA )
            .Compile() );

    foreach( var b in filteredResults )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}/{1}", b.ID, b.EntityA.ID );
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```